# Can't trigger event onclick on radio button

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, radio-button

I build a keyword-based testing framework, use Selenium 3.x, Java. I have a web element:

```
<input id="radiobutton" name="webserviceBarFlg" onclick="setReadOnly(this)" class="foo-input-radio-margin  foo-input-radio" type="radio" value="true" checked="checked">
<input id="radiobutton" name="webserviceBarFlg" onclick="setReadOnly(this)" class="foo-input-radio-margin  foo-input-radio" type="radio" value="false" checked="checked">
```

method Javascript affect to other input.

```
    function setReadOnly(obj) {
        var varRadio = $(obj).val();
        var input = $(obj).closest("tr").next("tr").find("input");
        if(varRadio == "false") {
            $(input).attr("readOnly",true);
        } else{
            $(input).attr("readOnly",false);
        }
    }
```

I try 2 solutions (on Internet Explorer 11, Windows 10 Pro):

**Solution 1**

```
webElement.click();
```

**Solution 2**

```
private RemoteWebDriver remoteWebDriver;
//...

JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) remoteWebDriver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", webElement);
```

but I still can't trigger event onclick. How to do it?

Comment: Is there any code after this click?

Comment: Are you sure you are locating the correct element and not getting another one with the same locator?

Comment: correct element, I seen it clicked on my screen, but can't call method `setReadOnly` on other text input. My problem is Selenium can't trigger event `onclick`.

Comment: You can't force onclick event with selenium if it's not triggered after click, use javascript instead to force onclick.

Comment: How do you locating the element ?

Comment: I use XPath `(//*[@id="radiobutton"])[1]` and `(//*[@id="radiobutton"])[2]`

Answer (score 1):

You have to define your setReadOnly(this) function if I'm not mistaken